# IceFaces Window scope not working properly on some browsers

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

I am running into weird problems when using window scope in IceFaces 3.3. When I put debug statements on constructor and destroy method (using pre-destroy annotation), I am seeing that the same bean is being created and destroyed and re-created when a single user navigates between pages. I checked the access logs on the tomcat server and it shows that the user is using a compatible browser like IE8 and is not opening any new tabs other than navigating between the pages.

What is the lifecycle of a window scoped bean. What triggers a window scope bean to be destroyed?

This behavior does not happen consistently on the same browsers. It happens for some users using IE8 while not others. But most of the cases where the bean is re-created seem to be the cases where the user is behind some kind of proxy. Would the proxy be causing such a behavior? but then again the users session remains valid i.e. the session which keep tracks the name of the user etc., stays the same between pages.

How can this behavior be solved. Is window scope unreliable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's unreliable and perhaps doesn't serve the purpose of window scoping. You need to implement your own custom scope and not the icefaces predefined `#{window}`. The class `org.icefaces.application.WindowScopeManager` should give you some hints as to why you are seeing the behavior.